# GCP BigQuery ODBC connection issue

Tags: google-bigquery, odbc

Recently our company decommissioned GCP SSO authentication and switched to Company Single Sign On, since then our login to accounts.google.com page is failing.

There is no firewall issue, we are advised internally to add accounts.google.com in whitelisting in proxy server, everything is there in place.

One observation is, its switching to accounts.google.co.in, as per country re-direction setting, is this something we need to whitelist accounts.google.co.in as well?

Such that if there are users in other regions those URL to be added as well?

Trying to login to ODBC and create token, that is when facing the issue

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.